# How to get list of followers using Twitter Fabric Android?

Tags: java, android, rest, twitter

I want to use Twitter Rest Api without using twitter4j. Fabric is fine but i couldn't find a method like gettingUserFollowers(). I don't know why it has. Anyway I want to call my user followers ids using this service. https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids

I have looked a tutorial from fabric website(http://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/access-rest-api.html#tweets). There is a class for getting a custom service. But i couldn't understan how i can call it sending parameter.I changed it as following

```
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiClient;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.Query;

public class MyTwitterApiClient extends TwitterApiClient  {

    public MyTwitterApiClient(TwitterSession session) {
        super(session);
    }

    public CustomService getCustomService() {
        return getService(CustomService.class);
    }

    interface CustomService {
        @GET("/1.1/followers/ids.json")
        void show(@Query("user_id") long id);
   }
}
```

I think when i send an id ,service brings followers ids.

```
MyTwitterApiClient aa = new MyTwitterApiClient(session);
aa.getCustomService().show(userId);
```

But app is stopped.What is my wrong ?

LogCat is

```
5897-15897/com.tumymedia.tumer.lylafortwitter E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tumymedia.tumer.lylafortwitter, PID: 15897
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=140, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.tumymedia.tumer.lylafortwitter/com.tumymedia.tumer.lylafortwitter.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CustomService.show: Must have either a return type or Callback as last argument.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4058)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4101)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1497)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CustomService.show: Must have either a return type or Callback as last argument.
            at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.methodError(RestMethodInfo.java:123)
            at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parseResponseType(RestMethodInfo.java:285)
            at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.<init>(RestMethodInfo.java:113)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter.getMethodInfo(RestAdapter.java:213)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:236)
            at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
            at com.tumymedia.tumer.lylafortwitter.$Proxy16.show(Unknown Source)
            at com.tumymedia.tumer.lylafortwitter.MainActivity$1.success(MainActivity.java:55)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient$CallbackWrapper.success(TwitterAuthClient.java:230)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.success(Callback.java:40)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.AuthHandler.handleOnActivityResult(AuthHandler.java:91)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(TwitterAuthClient.java:161)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(TwitterLoginButton.java:131)
            at com.tumymedia.tumer.lylafortwitter.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:96)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6543)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4054)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4101)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1497)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: seriously fabric has deficiencies? :D lol

Comment: Maybe not lol :) I couldn't find a method like getting followers

Comment: Do you know how can i use that rest ?

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: Can you tell me how can write java code using that rest api Link(https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids)

Comment: I have posted complete code as answer to solve your problem. Please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Actually Fabric uses retrofit to make REST Api calls and as mentioned
>   in Fabric documentation, for getting ids of followers we need to pass
>   user_id as parameter and retrieve list in response.

MyTwitterApiClient.java

```
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiClient;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import retrofit.client.Response;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.Query;

    public class MyTwitterApiClient extends TwitterApiClient {
        public MyTwitterApiClient(TwitterSession session) {
            super(session);
        }

        /**
         * Provide CustomService with defined endpoints
         */
        public CustomService getCustomService() {
            return getService(CustomService.class);
        }
    }

    // example users/show service endpoint
    interface CustomService {
        @GET("/1.1/followers/ids.json")
        void list(@Query("user_id") long id, Callback<Response> cb);
    }
```

> Now in MainActivity we will authenticate the user and then by getting
>   the session we will retrieve the list of all followers corresponding
>   to a userid.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Note: Your consumer key and secret should be obfuscated in your source code before shipping.
    private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "YOUR_TWITTER_KEY";
    private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "YOUR_TWITTER_SECRET";
    TwitterLoginButton loginButton;
    SharedPreferences shared;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig), new Crashlytics());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        shared = getSharedPreferences("demotwitter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
           @Override
           public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
               // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
                TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager()
                        .getActiveSession();
                TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                String token = authToken.token;
                String secret = authToken.secret;

//Here we get all the details of user's twitter account

                System.out.println(result.data.getUserName()
                        + result.data.getUserId());
                Twitter.getApiClient(session).getAccountService()
                        .verifyCredentials(true, false, new Callback<User>() {

                            @Override
                            public void success(Result<User> userResult) {

                                User user = userResult.data;
//Here we get image url which can be used to set as image wherever required.      
                 System.out.println(user.profileImageUrl+" "+user.email+""+user.followersCount);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void failure(TwitterException e) {

                            }

                        });
                shared.edit().putString("tweetToken", token).commit();
                shared.edit().putString("tweetSecret", secret).commit();
                TwitterAuthClient authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
                authClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<String> result) {
                        // Do something with the result, which provides the
                        // email address
                        System.out.println(result.toString());
                        Log.d("Result", result.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.data,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                        // Do something on failure
                        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
                    }
                });
                MyTwitterApiClient apiclients=new MyTwitterApiClient(session);
                apiclients.getCustomService().list(result.data.getUserId(), new Callback<Response>() {

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<Response> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        BufferedReader reader = null;
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        try {

                            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(arg0.response.getBody().in()));

                            String line;

                            try {
                                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                    sb.append(line);
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        String result = sb.toString();
                    System.out.println("Response is>>>>>>>>>"+result);
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(result);
                        JSONArray ids=obj.getJSONArray("ids");
              //This is where we get ids of followers
                        for(int i=0;i<ids.length();i++){
                        System.out.println("Id of user "+(i+1)+" is "+ids.get(i));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }

                });
           }

           @Override
           public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
               // Do something on failure
           }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result to the login button.
        loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So i can use this code style for other restful jsons;)

Comment: yes for more help you can reach at: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/07/22/twitter-fabric-integration/#more-2

Comment: Sorry to disturb you but I get 

TwitterApiException: No authentication challenges found

Error

Comment: have you passed your key and secret in the code above, may be this is the issue, you need the pass those which will find over your fabric account, if still issue exists post your logcat seperately or may be post a question.

Comment: I got this error - Error:(99, 46) error: list(long,Callback<Response>) in CustomService is defined in an inaccessible class or interface - could you help?

Comment: It is clear from the error that CustomService is inaccessible from where you are trying to access, check out and if still problem exists, you can share your code

Comment: this is not answer for this question. you cannot return void in customservice.

Comment: in reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(arg0.response.getBody().in()));                      getBody() method can not be resolved. Please help

Comment: @Awadesh make sure its import retrofit2.Response; and not import okHttp3.Response;

Answer (score 1):

In Retrofit 2.0,
Interface ->

```
public interface FollowersService {
        @GET("/1.1/followers/list.json")
        Call<ResponseBody> list(@Query("screen_name") String userId);
}
```

Call to method ->

```
FollowersService followersService = followersTwitterApiClient.getFollowersService();
        Call<ResponseBody> call = followersService.list(userId);
        call.enqueue(followerCallback);
```

Custom Api client ->

```
public class FollowersTwitterApiClient extends TwitterApiClient {

    public FollowersTwitterApiClient(TwitterSession twitterSession){
        super(twitterSession);
    }

    public FollowersService getFollowersService(){
        return getService(FollowersService.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to authenticate to Twitter in order to be able to call the API and get results. I don't see that happening in this code. (Maybe you are doing it outside this code?)

Details on Twitter authentication at https://dev.twitter.com/oauth

Comment: I have already authenticated. I can take userId,username so on.