# Twitter's followers list using Fabric

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric

I was trying to retrieve followers list using fabric API. I followed answers in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106290/how-to-get-list-of-followers-using-twitter-fabric-android) and an article [here](https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/07/22/twitter-fabric-integration/).

And I have tried something like this:

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig(getString(R.string.consumerKey), getString(R.string.consumerSecret));
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig), new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk(), new MoPub());
}
```

}

**Method to fetch list**

```
public void getList() {
    TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
    MyTwitterApiClient apiclients = new MyTwitterApiClient(session);
    apiclients.getCustomService().list(session.getUserId(), new Callback<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<Response> result) {
            Log.d("Debug", "Sucess");
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {
            Log.d("Debug", "Failed "+e.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

**MyTwitterApiClient.java**

```
public class MyTwitterApiClient extends TwitterApiClient {
   public MyTwitterApiClient(TwitterSession session) {
        super(session);
   }

   public CustomService getCustomService() {
        return getService(CustomService.class);
   }
}

interface CustomService {
    @GET("/1.1/followers/ids.json")
    void list(@Query("user_id") long id, Callback<Response> cb);
}
```

Now when I run this code it throws failure message like this:

```
10-26 20:18:03.841 14232-14232/np.com.aawaz.whounfriendedme D/Debug: com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: No authentication challenges found
```

What does this mean and how to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance!!!